# Push to external object from inside a map function with a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I know this is a hot topic on stackoverflow, but I'm running into an issue while filling an external object with a promise function.

So basically what I want to do:

- Through a promise get an array of objects I want to iterate over
- Iterate over this array with a map function. Call a promise with each iteration
- After this second promise resolves I want to push an Id and the result of the promise to an array

Naturally I cannot use a global object, because the promise will not be in the right scope. I have also experimented with Bluebird Promise.map function, but this way I am not able to push to the object more than only the second promise results.

Here is my code so far. PromiseTwo should populate an object, which I want to show in the res.json function (this is an Express/NodeJS app)

```
let promise = actie.groupActies()
let akties = {}
promise.then(function(aktieMaanden) {
    let values = aktieMaanden.forEach((aktie) => {
        let aktieId = aktie['_id']
        let artikelen = aktie['artikelen']
        let promiseTwo = order.getActieArtikelenOmzet(artikelen)
        promiseTwo.then(function(orders) {
            akties[aktieId] = orders
            return akties
        })
    })
    return akties
}).then((akties) => {
    res.json({ message: "Omzet voor aktie", akties: akties })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Through a promise get an array of objects I want to iterate over

```
actie.groupActies()
```

> Iterate over this array with a map function. Call a promise with each iteration

```
.then( acties => Promise.all(
  acties.map(actie => 
    order.getActieArtikelenOmzet(actie.artikelen)
    .then(orders => [actie._id,orders])
  )
 ))
```

> After this second promise resolves I want to push an Id and the result of the promise to an array

```
.then(results=> res.json({results}))
```

The main idea here is to use Promise.all so that it only continues if *all* orders have finished.

Comment: Yes, super, thanks for that. The trick was in .the(orders => [actie._id,orders], which returned an object.

I can even write it smaller with Promise.map:
 `actie.groupActies()
 .then(acties => Promise.map(acties, actie =>
   order.getActieArtikelenOmzet(actie.artikelen)
   .then(orders => [actie._id,orders])
  ))
 .then(results => {
  res.json({ message: "Omzet voor aktie", akties: results })
 })`

Comment: @patrick steenks thats a good solution too. Ypu could that as an answer for future readers... ( and actually my solution does return a 2d array and not an array of objects ;)

Comment: Did that, thanks. Now working on returning an array of objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the answer of Jonas w, using Promise.map the following works as well:

```
actie.groupActies()
.then(acties =>
    Promise.map(acties, actie =>
       order.getActieArtikelenOmzet(actie.artikelen)
       .then(orders => [actie._id,orders])
    )
)
.then(results => {
   res.json({ message: "Omzet voor aktie", akties: results})
})
```